# How to shutdown from a script without being root?

Tags: amazon-ec2, root

I've got an amazon EC2 instance, which starts up, runs a script, and when the script finishes, I want to shut it down.

I tried chmod g+s to give super user privileges on a .sh script which called shutdown, but that didnt work. Is there another way?

Or should I use the amazon API instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are using Linux-based instance.

Use sudo to grant your script user permission to run shutdown with root privileges.

edit your sudoers file with `visudo` and put this line

```
scriptuser    ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

After that your script can shutdown machine with command `/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/shutdown`